# JSON Parsing, Objective c

Tags: objective-c, json

```
callback({"success":"TRUE","total_records":1,"data":[{"status_value":"1","status_text":"Login Successful","user_id":"5","u_name":"Tushar Verma"}]})
```

I have a service which gives the above result,
 so how can i get the **data** value using json parsing in objective c.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: use NSJASONSerialization

Comment: your json is wrong. Check it [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Answer (score 0):

The [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is available to iOS from 5.0 onwards.

It provides convenient methods to convert the data representation of JSON response from a server to the appropriate NSArray or NSDictionary methods.

It's harder to give a more detailed answer as you've asked such a general question.

Answer (score 0):

use this simple code :-

```
NSString *str = @"{\"success\":\"TRUE\",\"total_records\":1,\"data\":[{\"status_value\":\"1\",\"status_text\":\"Login Successful\",\"user_id\":\"5\",\"u_name\":\"Tushar Verma\"}]}";
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
NSArray *arr =[dic objectForKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@"%@", arr);
```